# Incorrect calculation of the amount in the request postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with site visits **user_activity_log**

| id | client_id | hitdatetime | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2661715 | 17 | 2020-09-18 11:30:43 | visit |
| 2661716 | 17 | 2020-09-18 11:30:54 | registration |
| 2661717 | 17 | 2020-09-18 11:31:16 | visit |

There is also a table **user_payment_log**

| id | client_id | hitdatetime | action | payment_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 | 2021-08-12 03:43:02.176 | open-paystation | 0.00 |
| 2 | 30 | 2021-08-12 03:43:02.665 | choose-method | 0.00 |
| 3 | 30 | 2021-08-12 03:43:07.463 | accept-method | 0.00 |

I want to combine these tables to get the field **total_payment_amount**, where the sum of all the user's expenses for the entire time will be indicated.

I make the following request

```sql
SELECT user_activity_log.client_id, 
  SUM(user_payment_log.payment_amount) as total_payment_amount
FROM user_payment_log RIGHT JOIN user_activity_log
ON user_activity_log.client_id = user_payment_log.client_id
GROUP BY user_activity_log.client_id 
ORDER BY client_id;
```

and I get

| client_id | total_payment_amount |
| --- | --- |
| 0 |  |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 | 632.39 |
| 4 |  |

When this field **total_payment_amount** is calculated incorrectly. Here are all the values of the table **user_payment_log** for a user with client_id = 3

| id | client_id | hitdatetime | action | payment_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76 | 3 | 2021-08-11 03:18:09.978 | open-paystation | 0.00 |
| 77 | 3 | 2021-08-11 03:18:10.535 | choose-method | 0.00 |
| 78 | 3 | 2021-08-11 03:18:12.409 | accept-method | 0.00 |
| 79 | 3 | 2021-08-11 03:18:27.09 | make-payment | 57.49 |
| 80 | 3 | 2021-08-11 03:19:27.618 | open-paystation | 0.00 |

Where did I make a mistake?

**Update:**
The desired result for client_id = 3 is increased exactly 11 times.The next client_id that spent funds is 10.

**Update:**
Crooked, but solved

```sql
SELECT t.client_id, 
  SUM(user_payment_log.payment_amount) as total_payment_amount
FROM user_payment_log 
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT client_id FROM user_activity_log) as t
        ON t.client_id = user_payment_log.client_id
        GROUP BY t.client_id
```

Comment: user_payment_log and user_payment_amount are two different tables.

Comment: Thanks. But this is only an error in the description. I didn't use user_payment_amount in the code

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN user_activity_log`  replicates one payment by numbers of records in activity

Comment: And how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got what I wanted, albeit crookedly. If there is a better option, please write

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate first, then join to the result of the aggregation:

```
select act.*, pl.total_payment_amount
from user_activity_log act
  left join (
      select client_id, sum(payment_amount) as total_payment_amount
      from user_payment_log
      group by client_id
  ) pl on pl.client_id = act.client_id
```